# cx_Freeze ValueError when including venv in include_files: Path not in subpath or one path is relative and the other is absolute

Tags: python, cx-freeze

when i add venv to include_files, it throws error:

```
ValueError: '/home/User/temp2/t/X/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.10/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pillow.libs/libopenjp2-eca49203.so.2.5.0' is not in the subpath of '/home/User/temp2/t/X/build/exe.linux-x86_64-3.10/lib' OR one path is relative and the other is absolute.
```

by removing it, there will be no more errors.